# Android iFrame Browser Support

Tags: android, html, browser, iframe

Does anyone know how well the iFrame HTML tag is supported on Android?  Some of my preliminary research indicates that it is supported, but scrolling can be hit or miss and should be avoided.  Is there documentation on this anywhere or am I going to have to get ahold of devices to test on?

Comment: I definitely recommend getting a device as I personally have noticed vastly different behavior on webviews in the emulator versus a device.

Answer (score 0):

Android supports the iFrame tag but not the scroll attribute. I had the same issue. Leave off the scroll attribute and the iFrame will display.

Comment: I have been facing the same problem. Unable to make the iframe to scroll on my android. Is there any solution? I need to display the webpage with iframes in a webview. This must be loaded only inside the application instead of opening outside the app !

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how Android handles frames, plus different Android roms use different browsers.

What I do know is that as of HTML5 frames are deprecated, therefore not a very good practise. If not anything you are going to have more and more compatibility issues with new browsers in the future.

Why don't you do the request on the same page? If the downloader.php has the proper headers the download process should start without breaking or changing the current page at all.

> Hence sorry to say but Android has no support for **iframe** though **ios** have it.